# Calling block on a nil object gives exc_bad_access

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I came across this scenario where my app was crashing with exec_bad_access when I call a block on a nil object. I was able to fix the issue by add a if condition but I want to know why calling block on a nil object causes bad_access?

```
@interface CustomView :UIView

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImage* sourceImage;
@property (nonatomic, copy) void(^doneSwipingBlock)();

- (void)testMethod;

@end

//Another Class
//Sample Code (this is not the actual code but shows the crash 
CustomView view = nil;
view.sourceImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]; //no error as view is nil
[view testMethod]; //no error as view is nil
view.doneSwipingBlock();  //Crashes here

/*
//This works fine
if (view.doneSwipingBlock) {
    view.doneSwipingBlock();
}
*/
```

Comment: You're missing a `*` in your `CustomView view` declaration. Are you sure the code that's crashing is copied into this message verbatim?

Comment: @IanMacDonald: it says "//Sample Code (this is not the actual code but shows the crash", so clearly it is not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because while blocks are objects, operations on blocks should not be perceived as respecting Objective-C semantics. Just like reading from NULL causes a bad access, invoking a NULL block causes a bad access. This is consistent with the behavior of a function pointer (calling a NULL function pointer crashes your program), and since blocks are available in C and C++ as well, it may have made more sense to use this behavior than a purely Objective-C behavior.

The invoke method is not called through `objc_msgSend`, which handles and cancels calls to nil objects on Objective-C objects.

Blocks are variables, not methods. You can expect the same things out of a block property than you can out of an `int` property. They're just like you had some class called `Block` that had an `invoke` method on it, and you subclassed it every time you needed it to do something different, except that the compiler does all the subclassing part.

Comment: I believe the interpreter performs this action: `view.doneSwipingBlock()` -> `nil.doneSwipingBlock()` -> `[nil doneSwipingBlock]()` -> `nil()` `**crash`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. So, with blocks can't I have some thing similar to a required delegate method, where the CustomView object has to set doneSwipingBlock block. If I have the if (view.doneSwipingBlock) condition then I can create a CustomView object with no doneSwipingBlock. Is there a way I can force to set the doneSwipingBlock similar to required delegate method or should I rather just use delegates?

Comment: Yes @IanMacDonald, the property on the nil object returns nil per Objective-C rules, and invoking nil crashes per block rules.

Comment: @Sam, protocols can't enforce runtime properties. A protocol can force you to implement a method, but it can't force you to call it, so if you use a getter to access the block, you must be ready for the eventuality that its setter was never used. You can't create a special type of block (with the same level of language support) that can be called when it's nil.

Comment: You have several options here, that without context all seem valid to me: you could provide a default block in the `init` method and implement the setter in such a way that would fail/restore the default block if the argument is nil; you could have a method to invoke the block, and you would only need the nil check on the block in there; you could use delegates.